# javascript change color of all elements valid in the form

Tags: javascript, html, function, validation, input

[formulaire](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ecvWa.png)

Create a function allowing form elements to have a red background color (#FFEDED) when it takes focus, and once the value entered is valid will have a blue background color (#EDF7FC)

Comment: your question isn't specific but this might help https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_valid.asp

Answer (score 0):

For focus you can use CSS and the :focus pseudo class. Please check this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus).

It will look something like:

```
input:focus { color: "#FFEDED"; }
```

For validation you need to change the style depending on a function that will validate your requirements. Please check this [link](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_css.asp)

i.e.

```
document.getElementById("form").style.color = "#EDF7FC";
```